# Linux command or script counting duplicated lines in a text file?

Tags: linux, text, duplicates

If I have a text file with the following conent

```
red apple
green apple
green apple
orange
orange
orange
```

Is there a Linux command or script that I can use to get the following result?

```
1 red apple
2 green apple
3 orange
```

Answer (score 260, accepted):

Send it through `sort` (to put adjacent items together) then `uniq -c` to give counts, i.e.:

```
sort filename | uniq -c
```

and to get that list in sorted order (by frequency) you can

```
sort filename | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

Comment: I used this to count installed RPM packages and licenses: `$ rpm -qa --qf "%{license}\n" | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr > ~/license_counts`. More info [here](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/using-rpm-command-to-count-the-numbers-of-license-791962/#post6265960). Thanks.

Answer (score 62):

Almost the same as borribles' but if you add the `d` param to `uniq` it only shows duplicates.

```bsh
sort filename | uniq -cd | sort -nr
```

Comment: Thumbs up for the little `-d` note.

Comment: Good tip, although OP specifically seems to want "1 red apple" lines in the output as well.

Answer (score 8):

`uniq -c file`

and in case the file is not sorted already:

`sort file | uniq -c`

Answer (score 6):

```
cat <filename> | sort | uniq -c
```

Comment: Except [the `cat` is useless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat)

Answer (score 2):

Can you live with an alphabetical, ordered list:

```
echo "red apple
> green apple
> green apple
> orange
> orange
> orange
> " | sort -u
```

?

```
green apple
orange
red apple
```

or

```
sort -u FILE
```

-u stands for unique, and uniqueness is only reached via sorting.

A solution which preserves the order:

```
echo "red apple
green apple
green apple
orange
orange
orange
" | { old=""; while read line ; do   if [[ $line != $old ]]; then  echo $line;   old=$line; fi ; done }
red apple
green apple
orange
```

and, with a file

```
cat file | { 
old=""
while read line
do
  if [[ $line != $old ]]
  then
    echo $line
    old=$line
  fi
done }
```

The last two only remove duplicates, which follow immediately - which fits to your example.

```
echo "red apple
green apple
lila banana
green apple
" ...
```

Will print two apples, split by a banana.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
cat myfile.txt| sort| uniq
```

Comment: without the -c or -d flags, uniq doesn't distinguish duplicate lines from non-duplicates, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

To just get a count:

```
$> egrep -o '\w+' fruits.txt | sort | uniq -c

      3 apple
      2 green
      1 oragen
      2 orange
      1 red
```

To get a sorted count:

```
$> egrep -o '\w+' fruits.txt | sort | uniq -c | sort -nk1
      1 oragen
      1 red
      2 green
      2 orange
      3 apple
```

**EDIT**

Aha, this was NOT along word boundaries, my bad. Here's the command to use for full lines:

```
$> cat fruits.txt | sort | uniq -c | sort -nk1
      1 oragen
      1 red apple
      2 green apple
      2 orange
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a simple python script using the [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) type. The benefit is that this does not require sorting the file, essentially using zero memory:

```py
import collections
import fileinput
import json

print(json.dumps(collections.Counter(map(str.strip, fileinput.input())), indent=2))
```

Output:

```
$ cat filename | python3 script.py
{
  "red apple": 1,
  "green apple": 2,
  "orange": 3
}
```

or you can use a simple one-liner:

```
$ cat filename | python3 -c 'print(__import__("json").dumps(__import__("collections").Counter(map(str.strip, __import__("fileinput").input())), indent=2))'
```

Comment: As an aside, you want to avoid the [useless `cat`s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat)