# How to find number of commits done to a file across a repository

Tags: git, github, version-control, git-svn, git-commit

i was looking at a video "Treat Your Code as a Crime Scene".

http://www.infoq.com/presentations/code-bugs-legacy-pitfalls

inorder to know the complexity of the code he says to find the the number of commits done over to each file.This means that those file need more maintainance. how do i find hotspot like this guy done in this video.

This is between 13:20 - 14:20 in that video.

[image: Treat Your code as crime scene]

[image: Treat you code as crime scene 2]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following "[How to count number of commits per file pathname by author in a Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28647880/6309)", you can start with:

```
git log --name-only --pretty=format: | sort | uniq -c | sort
```

The sorted list will help you spot the files with *a lot* of commits.